# Плагин для nanoCad 10.0 plus x64 используя QT

Tags: c++, qt, autocad

Стоит задача написать простой плагин для этой САПР системы используя инструменты NRX и фреймворк QT. В процессе работы возникла проблема, которую решить не могу до сих пор. Когда я в обычном каркасе создаю любой объект QT, например QApplication app(argc, argv), то nanoCad ругается и пишет что приложение не является Win32. Использую MSVC 2012 update 5, QT версии 5.0.2. 2012_64

Comment: А приложения является приложением Win32? Какая у него битность 32 или 64? А какая битность требуется?

Comment: Здрасьте. Проверил создаваемую DLL посредством dumpbin. Библиотека х64 и нужна мне х64.

Comment: dll - а откуда вдруг `QApplication app(argc, argv)`?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы вызывалось окно для работы с САПР

Comment: А сам NanoCad это позволяет? Если да, то скорее всего ему нужно передать дескриптор окна - тут все зависит от того как это вообще сделано в NanoCad. QApplication app(argc, argv) использовать в dll нельзя т.к. это не приложение,а библиотека. Скорее всего для создания плагина тебе нужно экспортировать некоторые функции, прописанные в документации. Там же должны быть заголовочные файлы для прототипов этих функций. Ищи примеры в документации и приводи их в вопросе - сомневаюсь, что тут есть спецы по NanoCad.

Comment: Если это делать используя MFC, то можно. Но вот с QT проблем просто дофига, я уже неделю почти сижу дабы запустить